# Riemann sum simplifying for the integral of an exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

I am studying for a calculus class(using Stewart) and this question came up in a list of exercises (from my university):

Question $\rightarrow$   Find  $\int_{a}^{b}e^xdx$

I reached $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(b-a)e^a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{\frac{(b-a)i}{n}}$$

and I should be able to solve it if I knew $\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^n$. The  resolution of the list of exercises only brushes it off by making $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{\frac{(b-a)i}{n}}=\frac{e^{\frac{(b-a)}{n}}(e^{\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)n}-1)}{e^{\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)}-1}$$

How can you prove this?

Comment: Think [Geometric series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeometricSeries.html) ...

Comment: It will be a GP

Comment: It is the partial sum of a geometric series: in general $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{n-1} = a\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}$ when $r\not=1$, and here $a=r=e$

Comment: @Henry Isn't $a=r=e^{(b-a)/n}$?

Comment: @Gary - I was looking at $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}e^k$ (the title question and "if I knew") while you were looking at $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}e^{\frac{(b-a)i}{n}}$ (the underlying question in the text).

Comment: @Henry The "if I knew" part makes no sense since the terms do not depend on $i$. And even if $n$ was $i$ it would not help the OP in solving the problem (unless $e$ denotes a generic constant).